# How to get div class from html page?

Tags: php, html

I have this portion of html code:

```
<h1 class="float_left margin_right margin_bottom">NiccolÃ² Campriani</h1>
    <div class="clear_left"></div>
    <p><span class="bold_text">Full name:</span> Niccolò Campriani
    <br><span class="bold_text">Nickname(s):</span> Nicco
    <br><span class="bold_text">Gender:</span> Male
    <br><span class="bold_text">Height:</span> 5-9.5 (177 cm)
    <br><span class="bold_text">Weight:</span> 176 lbs (80 kg)
    <br><span class="bold_text">Born:</span> <span id="necro-birth" data-birth="1987-11-06"><a href="/olympics/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=11&amp;day=6">November 6</a>, 1987</span> in <a href="/olympics/friv/birthplaces.cgi?id=10713">Sesto Fiorentino, Firenze, Italy</a>
```

I'm using this (portion of) php code with no success:

```
foreach($html2->find($tagname_td) as $tag2) {

              if(strpos($athlete_link = $tag2->href,'athletes') == true){


                    $url_athlete='https://www.sports-reference.com' . $athlete_link;

                    $html3 = file_get_html($url_athlete,true);

              }

                           $dom = new DOMDocument();
                           $dom->loadHTML($html3);

                           $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
                           $div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="clear_left"]');
                           $div = $div->item(0);
                           $result = $dom->saveXML($div);
                           echo $result;

 }
```

I put echo $result only to see what it stamps, but what I want is to get this information e store them in variables, i.e.:

```
Name = Niccolò
Surname= Campriani
Gender= male
birth = 1987-11-06
City = Sesto Fiorentino, Firenze
```

How can I do?

Comment: get the class attribute of the node http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php

Comment: You can also parse you html from DomDocument : https://eval.in/885908

Answer (score 0):

To get a class element using **javascript** :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('clear_left');
```

To get a class element using **jquery** :

```
$('div .clear_left')
```

Comment: Yes @Thielicious but i just gave the snippet to give an idea